# Restore chrome dev tool snippets from offline Windows 10 HDD

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, code-snippets

I've decided to upgrade my laptop and reinstall windows 10. It is always risky, but I had to do it. Now I realize that I didn't copy/backup chrome dev tool snippets that I was working on.

I tried to search in:

```
C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default
```

But couldn't find anything.

Is there a way to find those snippets on an HDD of an old system?

Comment: Make a dummy snippet, exit Chrome and copy `scriptSnippets` from the old `Preferences` file into the new file.

Comment: WOW, it was in the Preferences file all the time! Look I was searching in all files for  
 querySelectorAll("div.    as that was a part of the code snippet and it turned out that " was escaped with \\\, can't believe my bad luck. Thanks so much